# Turning numeric column to year and month duration in r

Tags: r, time, duration, time-format

This is a part of my df, which represents relationship duration:

```
   r_duration_1 r_duration_2
3             0            4
4             1            4
5             2            4
6             0            9
7             1            3
8             5            0
9             0            9
10            0           11
```

duration_1 represents years and duration_2 represents months.
How can I turn these columns from numeric to a duration that I can do operations on it like mean relationship duration and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the data as it is. Average relationship duration in months can be calculated as :

```
mean(with(df, r_duration_1 * 12 + r_duration_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums` after multiplying with different weights and get the `mean`

```
mean(rowSums(df * c(12, 1)[col(df)]))
```

---

Or using `Map/Reduce`

```
mean(Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, df, c(12, 1))))
```